# Windows-like visual style for Gnome/Cinnamon?

Tags: linux, theme

I'm secretly trying to replace a windows machine with Linux for a girl and make it look like Windows the way it is actually possible to.

I was unable to find appropriate apps like panel and menu launcher for that purpose except some GNOME themes.

What I need is a panel and a menu launcher for Linux that can simulate Windows XP/7. If there is any, do please link it.

Comment: I don't mean any offense and I'm sorry if this comment is off-topic, but are you sure this approach is a good idea? What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? If you want to persuade your friend into using Linux, you could for example burn a live-CD of a beginner-friendly distro and show her how Linux works and what you think it does better than Windows without manipulating her computer (I believe you wouldn't want to have this done to your machine either). That way she would also be able to ask questions if there is something she doesn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Zorin OS. You can get almost similar theme of Windows 7 and Windows xp.
Check out the [Screen Shots](http://www.zorin-os.com/gallery.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your using cinnamon desktop be sure to install gnome then install gnome panels for gnome classic then download win -2 7

Answer (score -1):

The [Tails LiveCD](https://tails.boum.org/) does a decent job of looking like a Windows Desktop, but it isn't perfect.  Some of the icons in the system tray aren't the same.

Here's a screenshot of the [Windows Camouflage](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/startup_options/windows_camouflage/index.en.html) option.

Comment: As of 2020, Windows Camouflage no longer exists in Tails